# How to change the colour of part of divider line in masterdetailpage(UISplitViewController) in popover behaviour?

Tags: ios, xamarin, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

[As visible in the below screen shot,the white thin line in the status bar portion is due to the divider line of masterdetailpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0VBn.png)I have masterdetailpage(UISplitViewController in iOS) in Xamarin forms with master behaviour as popover.
How can I make that portion of divider line black even with custom renderer.

any solution in xamarin iOS is also welcome.

I tried many ways by setting the background color of view etc., but no luck.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in Advance,
Harikrishna.

Answer (score 0):

This anwser is in Xamarin.iOS

`UISplitViewController` doesnt have a property to change that divider but you can try to add a view to cover it up like so in teh `ViewDidLoad` in the `MasteViewController`:

```
        var coverView = new UIView(new CGRect(320, 0, 1, 64));
        coverView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
        SplitViewController.View.AddSubview(coverView);
```

for example `ViewDidLoad` in the master/detail template project:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem = EditButtonItem;

            var addButton = new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, AddNewItem);
            addButton.AccessibilityLabel = "addButton";
            NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = addButton;

            DetailViewController = (DetailViewController)((UINavigationController)SplitViewController.ViewControllers [1]).TopViewController;

            TableView.Source = dataSource = new DataSource (this);

         // CODE not from template below
            var coverView = new UIView(new CGRect(320, 0, 1, 64));
            coverView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
            SplitViewController.View.AddSubview(coverView);
        }
```

The result is like this:
[image]

---

Comment: Thanks smith for fast reply, I will try and let you know.

Comment: No worries, let me know how you get on

Comment: Smith,It is working if the SplitViewController "Behaviour" is Split,But Divider line still exists if the "Behaviour" changed to "PopOver".I'm unable to add screen shots here,but issue exists,can you suggest way to resolve this issue in  "Popover" behaviour mode.